# How to use merge to insert value from a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to do something like this:

```
merge MembershipTEST as T
using (select OrganisationID, Name From MembershipPending) as S
on  T.OrganisationID = S.OrganisationID
and T.Name = S.Name
when not matched then
insert (MembershipID,OrganisationID, Name) 
values(
(EXEC [dbo].[spGetNextIntKeyByTableName] 
@PKColName = 'MembershipID',@TableName = 'FWBMembership'),
S.OrganisationID, 
S.Name );
```

Bascially the identitykey is from a sp

Is it possible?

Update 1: Answer is NO

read the online doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

> VALUES ( values_list) Is a comma-separated list of constants,
>   variables, or expressions that return values to insert into the target
>   table. Expressions cannot contain an EXECUTE statement.

Comment: [According to the publicly and freely available online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), the only valid thing in a `when not matched` clause is: `INSERT [ ( column_list ) ] { VALUES ( values_list ) | DEFAULT VALUES }` - so **no**, you **cannot** call a stored procedure in place of inserting data values

Comment: Uh, why not just `INSERT table EXEC dbo.procedure`? Why are you complicating this by trying to shoehorn `MERGE` into it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand it is a nightly run job, obviously I dont want to insert duplicated data

Comment: Ok, so `INSERT #tmp EXEC procedure; INSERT table SELECT FROM #tmp WHERE NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand the proc will return the max id fron the table, so it is not a result list i can store in a #tmp table.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

Build an SSIS package. Just create a new Data Flow task. Use two OLEDB sources make one of them execute the stored procedure and the other one select from the table you are looking to `MERGE` with. Make sure they are both ordered by the same thing. Go into advanced settings for each OLEDB source and set is sorted to true and then set the sort values for the items you are ORDERing BY. Then move both data flows to to a `MERGE JOIN`. Then send the Data flow to a Conditional Split and set as `INSULL(OrganisationID)`. Use the resulting data flow to go to an OLEDB destination.

Sorry for the lack of visuals I will add them later when I'm on lunch hour to busy to add them now.